# How to vertically center my div

Tags: css, html, center

I have a three column div and would like to vertically center the 3rd div (data_cell3). How would I do this?

I would like it vertically center align no matter how large the text area is.

Here's a link:
http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/UMf3k/89/

```
  <div class="wrapper-data">
<div class="data_row">
  <div class="data_cell1">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div> 
  <div class="data_cell2">

  </div>
    <div class="data_cell3">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.data_row{
    display:table;
}

.data_cell3{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This may require adjusting the css for the children of data_row since your widths may be off initially, but effectively you can achieve vertical centering this way.

http://jsfiddle.net/UMf3k/92/

For those of us who use sass, a coworker of mine contributed to the sass utility library by adding [scut](http://css-tricks.com/introducing-scut-new-sass-utility-library/) which makes this easy to reuse. Credits to [David Clark](http://osrc.dfm.io/davidtheclark) for developing scut.
Example scut usage:

```
@mixin vertically-center ($child: ".vcentered") {
  display: table;
  & > #{$child} {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

EDIT:
by making all your cells display:table-cell it will keep the widths as you have them. Currently you're mixing floats with display inline-block.

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep the widths at 49% - 2% - 49%

Comment: I updated the fiddle and added an explanation to my answer. Thanks

Comment: I'll throw in a link to the different vertical centering methods in Scut: http://davidtheclark.github.io/scut/#vertically_center. If you use Sass you could just use the mixins; otherwise, you could check the source code to see how they work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.data_row {
    position:relative;
}

.data_cell3 {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    height:5em; 
    margin-top:-2.5em; /* Half of above height */
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MCPv6/)

- Specify the parent container as position:relative or position:absolute.
- Specify a fixed height on the child container.
- Set position:absolute and top:50% on the child container to move the top down to the middle of the parent.
- Set margin-top:-yy where yy is half the height of the child container to offset the item up.

Source: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Comment: Do you have to set a fixed height on the client container? If I add more text to the paragraph, I have to increase the size of the height. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: For this answer you do need to set a fixed height. However, you should be able to dynamically adjust the height by counting/calculating the number of characters, etc.